# C# access Citrix through webinterface

Tags: c#, .net, citrix

I'm a newbie in programming, I inherited from a colleague some applications to manage or customize, but now I've been asked to develop a new application that accesses Citrix Receiver, and I will use C# VS2013.

After much research I found some tutorials and examples that they use a reference to wfica.ocx,but I must access to citrix through a webinterface:

https://webinterface.mycustomer.com/Citrix/ISPWeb/

I installed Citrix Receviver client and I don'k know to to invoke Citrix through webinterface.Does anybody know how to solve this issue?
Any advice is really appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: I highly doubt you want to use anything OCX.  ActiveX is very old and obsoleted.

Comment: Amy, how do you suggest to proceed instead?